# using conditions in calculations and assignments

Tags: c

Recently, I started using expressions like the following:

```
res += (i + n / i) * !(n % i);
```

Where I assume, that `!(n % i)` will always have a value of 1 or 0, and thus can be used in calculations directly, instead of writing lengthy if-statements like

```
if(!(n % i))
    res += (i + n / i);
```

In case you wonder, these lines are taken from a function I wrote to calculate the sum of proper divisors of a number `n`:

```
unsigned int sum_of_divisors(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int res = 1;

    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 2; i < sqrt(n); ++i)
            res += (i + n / i) * !(n % i);
    res += i * (i * i == n);

    return res;
}
```

My questions are, **is this code guaranteed to behave the way I intended it to behave?** What is the approximate performance impact of this (multiplication vs. conditional jump)? would the compiler do that anyway, if appropriate?

**EDIT**: Please note that I'm not particularly concerned about the performance of the actual code. I'd just like to know, out of pure professional interest, which one of the two would perform better, and why, and also how the compiler would handle each case.

As for the reason why I wrote it that way, it works well with my brain :)

It's hard to describe, but I've got a better feeling with multiplying 1 or 0 instead of ternary operators or if statements, at least in some cases.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is guaranteed to behave the way you expect.

No, it will not make your code faster, unless the compiler is really low-quality. The compiler should treat both versions of the code roughly equivalently and choose the way it thinks is best to do the conditional logic.

By the way, *in principle*, the `!` operator is a conditional branch. Some implementations (cpu archs) may have ways to optimize it not to need a real program-counter branch, but the same methods will work for most conditionals.

Note that there may be *one way* your code is "better" from the optimizing standpoint. In writing:

```
res += (i + n / i) * !(n % i);
```

you have given the compiler permission to write to `res` in both code paths. In the form:

```
if(!(n % i))
    res += (i + n / i);
```

the compiler can only write to `res` if the condition is true. If `res` is local and its address has not leaked, the compiler can determine that it's safe to perform excess writes anyway, but if the address of `res` is visible outside the function, the compiler must assume other threads may be able to access it and that code paths that don't modify `res` in the abstract machine must not modify it in the generated code (since they might not hold the lock necessary to modify it safely).

Comment: I'd give +2 if I could. +1 for the branching aspects of `!` and +1 for the multithreading issue. :) Thanks.

Comment: Threads? C11, is it? I am not too convinced of the second part of your answer.

Comment: It's impossible to have working threads if the compiler can introduce would-be-nop writes at arbitrary places. Both the POSIX and C11 memory models preclude this. Prior to C11, C has no memory model, but if it did, it would preclude such things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a general answer for "when to optimize". My personal take on the subject is that all optimization is premature until being directly asked to perform it. Heck sometimes I wait to be asked multiple times (just to be on the safe side that somebody *really* needs it).

Other than that, the first statement could also be written:

```
res += (n % i) ? 0 : (i + n / i);
```

As it stands the multiplication and the negation make it hard to understand.

#### EDIT

> is this code guaranteed to behave the way I intended it to behave

It is but could lead to subtle bugs if the first part (the one you multiply with 0 or 1) has side effects (like someone doing a ++). Like I said, just use the most natural form and worry about speed later.

Comment: Yes,I know about the ternary operator, thank you. I don't really like using it though, because it terribly messes with the look&feel of the code. (personal opinion :)

Comment: Also, please see the rephrased emphasis in the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator will always evaluate to 0 or 1, so your assumption is correct.

As for a performance impact, any optimizing compiler worth its salt should generate identical (or equivalent, performance-wise) code to an `if` statement or the ternary operator. If in doubt, check the assembly output (the `-S` switch if using gcc) or benchmark the code.